# Beginner question about getting a random object out of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I recently started with LPTHW. At exercise 39 I did a litle sidetracked and updated the code towards my ideas. It works as intended except it picks the item out of countries in order and I'd like if it would do in random.

Can I solve this easily or the whole thing is a dead end?
The idea is to pick a random element ask 1 of the 3 questions by random then compare if the answer is correct or not.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Sorry I could'nt  post the question unless I indented the images but after I did it is not clickable.

Comment: [You shouldn't be posting images of code in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
import random

random.choice(list(my_dict.keys()))
```

To select a random key from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to loop over every item in your `countries` dict as you do at the moment, just in a random order instead, then you can use `random.shuffle` to randomly shuffle a list.

So, one option would be to extract the keys of your dictionary into a list, shuffle them, and iterate over those to provide the randomness.

Try replacing line 63 with these four lines of code instead:

```
country_keys = list(countries.keys())
random.shuffle(country_keys)
for country in country_keys:
    abbrev = countries[country]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I wanted to shuffle them because the loop stops after 10 questions so not every item gets picked.